# Random number generator adds "-" for larger lengths

Tags: c, random

I'm writing a function in C that generates a sequence of random integers given the length of the sequence.  I've noticed that with numbers >66 the stdout shows "-" in between sets of numbers. How do I remove this and simply get a long string of integers?
Here is my segment of code and the stdout:

```
void gen_seq(int upper, int lower, int length) {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    char seq[length];
    int i, n;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        n = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower; // range of numbers to generate numbers from
        if (n != "-")
            seq[i] = n;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d", seq[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably (I've not studied the code to be sure) because you're using `%d` which is for signed numbers, and the numbers being printed are "large enough" to appear as negative.

Comment: The `-` is not a problem, but simply the sign of the signed number you are storing into your `signed char` array..

Comment: What are `upper` and `lower` set to?

Comment: What about `if (n != "-")` ? It is `int n`. was that an attempt to get rid of the supposed `'-'` character?

Comment: The `if (n != "-")` is comparing an `int` with a `char *` (the `"-"` is a string literal, which is stored as an anonymous array of `char`, which decays to a `char *` in this expression). This results in _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 3):

change the type of seq to int i.e.

```
int seq[length];
```

you are assigning an int to a char, so it is being casted to an 8-bit value. In 2s complement, the most significant bit determines the sign, which is why you are going negative.